# When doing an e-mail merge in Office 2010, Outlook forces me to approve EVERY email sent

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010, mail-merge

[image: A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf. If this is unexpected, click Deny and verify your antivirus software is up-to-date.]

When doing an email merge from Excel data, via a Word template, into Outlook (all Office 2010), I get the dialog displayed above. For **every single email**, I have to wait 5 seconds, then click the Allow button.

I'm not even using any scripting or VBA; this is just a straight email merge from Word. I find it confusing that there appears to be no easy way to disable this dialog. All the tips and fixes I can find for this involve fixing the issue for VBA or for an external program, not for Office applications internally. In fact, the directions ([from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-mail-merge-to-send-personalized-e-mail-messages-to-your-e-mail-address-list-HA010109162.aspx)) for doing email merges don't even mention this dialog at all. The last step at the bottom of that page is what I did just before two dialogs appeared; one that had me 'grant access' for 10 minutes to another program, and then this dialog over and over.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possibly related question: [email - Excel VBA code and Outlook Programmatic Access warning - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1094609/excel-vba-code-and-outlook-programmatic-access-warning) (that having said, the target question *does not* explain what is going on here because no scripting is done by the user)

Answer (score 1):

Start Outlook as an administrator (you may have to press **CTRL+Shift** to make this option appear when right clicking on the Outlook Shortcut).  Then click the **File** tab, select **Options** > **Trust Center** > **Trust Center Settings** > **Programmatic Access**.  Click **Never Warn me about suspicious activity**.  This will solve the problem.  I would recommend turning the warning back on after the mail merge, unless you do a lot of them.

Comment: If you do this, it's possible to mask a virus in that system.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a virus in system, at first, no other program should send e-mail thru Outlook unless you are beware of that (old small business CRM/ERP can do that). (If you use only Windows Defender, try another, like Kaspersky Free, make sure do a full scan).

After this, take a look in extensions/supplements at Outlook's options. Disable anything you are sure not using. Restart Outlook and see if solves.